# Erlang detach shell from node / Quit shell without killing node

Tags: erlang, rebar

I feel like I'm missing something stupid obvious, but I've looked all over and can't find the answer to my question.

Suppose I have an application release that I've built with rebar and I start it a la

```
rel/my_app/bin/my_app start
```

I let it happily go about its business for a while, and then I want to attach a console to check on things, so I do

```
rel/my_app/bin/my_app attach
```

and get a shell.  I muck around, and then when I'm done I want to quit the shell but leave the application running.  If I do `^G q` or `q().`, it brings down the entire application.

I've also played with starting the app with `+Bi` to stop it from allowing someone to accidentally close it, but then how does one even exit an attached shell at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't use rebar, I've never understood what problem it was meant to solve, but I assume when you "attach" you are doing the same thing as running `to_erl`.  To exit in from this you type control-D (EOF).

Comment: Commentary aside, you are correct :)   Now that you point it out I feel like a dunce because it clearly says "(^D to exit)" lol.

Comment: I use erl to start a new node (in Debian Linux 8, ssh terminal), but when I press Ctrl +D, nothing happens, why?

Answer (score 4):

`CTRL-D` should get you out and keep the app running.

Answer (score 0):

Eshell V10.7  (abort with ^G)

$ Ctrl^G
$  q

here，you can quit the remote console

Comment: I believe this will stop the application entirely, see the marked answer - Ctrl+D will detach and leave the application running.

Answer (score -5):

If it's an ordinary remote shell, hitting Ctrl-C twice ought to do the trick.

Comment: On behalf of an anonymous user: This approach will stop the shell. If you're attached to a running application's shell, you may not want to exit this way as it will quit and stop that application.